# data-image-src does not display parallax image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm finalizing this advertorial page: https://landingpagedude.ca/aff

But I'm having a problem in this section: https://i.ibb.co/092MdNG/screenshot.png

As you can see, the image below the ADVERTISEMENT is not displayed. The image is being pulled by `data-image-src="images/bgimg.png"` and `<script>
$ ('.parallax-window'). parallax ({imageSrc: 'images / bgimg.png'});
</ script>`

The image is in the correct directory but is not displayed. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the encoding of your image. If you select it in the network tab of your browser's inspector panel and attempt to preview it you'll see it's broken. Perhaps you renamed it as a png when it is actually a jpeg?

Try to save out the image again or attempt with a different image.

Comment: Very strange! Because the image is renamed as .png in both the HTML and the file. The file name is also correct ... Any other ideas?

Comment: I noticed that if I put the ADVERTISEMENT box, outside the article, for example over the header, the image appears. But inside the article (between the text of the news) does not appear ...

Comment: Or if I remove the style.css the image also appears (although I lose all styles of the site).